# Opción -s de read da error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, script, shell

Estoy con este script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash   
    
echo "Nombre"
    
echo "Apartado 2"
    
echo "Introduce un valor"
    
read var_num1
echo $var_num1
```

Se supone que con *read -s* se debería ocultar el contenido que escribes, pero cuando ejecuto script, me sale este error.

```
Nombre 

Apartado 2 

Introduce un valor

script.sh: 11: read: Illegal option -s
```

Comment: Qué versión de bash tienes? Osea, cual es el resultado del comando `bash --version`. Porque con el flag `read -s var_num1` no veo fallas.

Answer (score 2):

Tengo la sospecha que tiene que ver en cómo corres tu script.

Quizás lo corres así: `$ sh tu_script.sh`, es decir, usando el comando `sh`.

Hasta donde sé, `read` es un builtin tanto de *bash* como de *zsh*, pero no sé si de *dash/sh*, y otras shells minimalistas.

Intenta correr tu script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Nombre"
echo "Apartado 2"
echo "Introduce un valor"

read -s var_num1
echo "$var_num1"
```

Pero de esta manera:

```
$ bash tu_script.sh
```

O de esta:

```
$ chmod u+x tu_script.sh
$ ./tu_script.sh
```

Comment: Gracias!
Con $ bash tu_script.sh si me ha funcionado y me lo oculta correctamente.

Comment: Si te funcionó, podrías puntear positivamente mi respuesta y marcarla como aceptada para ayudar a que otros que tengan tu mismo problema sepan la solución que funcionó.